# Is there a file include mechanism for YACC files?

Tags: c, sed, bison, yacc

I have three programs that are currently using YACC files to do configuration file parsing.  For simplicity, they all read the same configuration file, however, they each respond to keys/values uniquely (so the same .y file can't be used for more than 1 program).  It would be nice not to have to repeat the `%token` declarations for each one - if I want to add one token, I have to change 3 files?  What year is it??

These methods aren't working or are giving me issues:

1. The C preprocessor is obviously run AFTER we YACC the file, so `#include` for a `#define` or other macro will not work.
2. I've tried to script up something similar using `sed`:

`REPLACE_DATA=$(cat <file>)`

`NEW_FILE=<file>.tmp`

`sed 's/$PLACEHOLDER/$REPLACE_DATA/g' <file> > $NEW_FILE`

However it seems that it's stripping my newlines in `REPLACE_DATA` and then not replacing instances of `$PLACEHOLDER` instead of replacing the contents of the variables `PLACEHOLDER`.

Is there a real include mechanism in YACC, or are there other solutions I'm missing?  This is a maintenance nightmare and I'm hoping someone else has run into a similar situation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) supports an `%include` directive.

Comment: You need to quote REPLACE_DATA to get it un-stripped.  You can not substitute variables with a single quote `'`, but have to use double quotes `"`.  I don't think this will help.  You can try `cat > output << EOF\n preample\n$(echo "$REPLACE_DATA)\npostamble"` or use another scripting language.

Comment: Nice Chris.  So does [bisoncpp](http://bisoncpp.sourceforge.net/bisonc++05.html#INCLUDE).

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise I did notice that double-quote bit about 2 minutes after I posted, but you're right it doesn't resolve it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I should probably switch to that...

Comment: I just switched to using a while-loop to get rid of the multiline issues, and stuck with a sed script (and double-quotes, of course).  It's not very elegant but it's better than modifying 3-6 files each time.

Answer (score 2):

here's a sed version from http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37

```
#!/bin/sh
# watch out for a '/' in the parameter
# use alternate search delimiter
sed -e '\_#INCLUDE <'"$1"'>_{
    r '"$1"'
    d
}'
```

But traditionally, we used the m4 preprocessor before yacc.